# getting number of rows deleted.?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

i want after delete **getting number of rows deleted** (How many of rows are deleted?). how is it?

Comment: What does the response of the server contain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MAYBE you can count the checked checkboxes, on your JavaScript:

```
var total = $(':checkbox:checked', '.ser_form').size();
alert(total + ' rows deleted');
```

This way you're not counting the deleted rows from the database, only the count of **checked checkboxes**.

Answer (score 4):

In your PHP code, you can retrieve the number of rows that were deleted by calling the [mysql_affected_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) function and then return that value back to your Javascript.

Your PHP code might look similar to this:

```
...
$query = "DELETE FROM myTable WHERE some_column=something";
mysql_query($query);
$number_of_rows_deleted = mysql_affected_rows();
return $number_of_rows_deleted;
...
```